# Good Alternative DBAL to Doctrine2 DBAL

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, dbal

I have a simple application that is set up to use Docrine2 DBAL, the problem is it needs to run on a host that only supports php 5.2.6. Doctrine requires PHP 5.3...

What is a good alternative Database Abstraction Layer for PHP? Should I simply convert everything to PDO? Or are there other good options?

Thanks.

Comment: I ended up going with PDO, it appears to be the best doctrine alternative. After all, doctrine is built around PDO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Zend_Db](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db) database abstraction layer?

Comment: I think this might be the second best option besides PDO because of its active development and the ease in which you can drop it into a project.

Answer (score 1):

Pear's [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2) was the standard for database abstraction before Doctrine came around. It's still a solid DBAL layer with pluggable adapters for which ever database you with to support.

Answer (score 0):

But Pear MDB2 won't run on PHP5.3 if you need it.  (As of 5/18/2011)

Answer (score 0):

You could have still used Doctrine 1.2 which is actually compatible with version < 5.3